# How to break out of nested loops in Dart

Tags: dart, nested-loops, break

Given the following nested loop:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    print('i: $i, j: $j');
  }
}
```

If I add a `break` statement to the inner loop:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    print('i: $i, j: $j');
    break; //                      <-- break
  }
}
```

It only breaks out of the inner loop. This is the output:

```
i: 0, j: 0
i: 1, j: 0
i: 2, j: 0
i: 3, j: 0
i: 4, j: 0
i: 5, j: 0
i: 6, j: 0
i: 7, j: 0
i: 8, j: 0
i: 9, j: 0
```

How do I break out of the outer loop?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Using a label

Dart supports labels. Create a label name and follow it with a colon:

```dart
outerLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    print('i: $i, j: $j');
    break outerLoop;
  }
}
```

In the example above, the label name is `outerLoop`, but you could have named it something else. Calling `break outerLoop` breaks out of the `for` loop that `outerLoop` is in front of.

This prints:

```dart
i: 0, j: 0
```

### Returning from a function

Another option is to put the nested loops inside a function and then just return from the function:

```dart
void myFunction() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      print('i: $i, j: $j');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to link to labels in the documentation, but I couldn't find a good place. Let me know if you know where it is.